# how to restrict scrollViewWillBeginDragging to only one sender object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios

i´ve built a nested scroll view. in the view.xib there is in the view one scrollview with vertical scrolling named rootScroll. in this one there are two other scrollviews with horizontal scrolling named topScroll and bottomScroll.

my goal is to fade out bottomScroll when user drags the topScroll and fade it in again when decelerating ends.

the code workes fine so far. the only problem is that scrollViewWillBeginDragging gets messages from all three UIScrollViews. i´ve logged the sender and can see that they´re different but anyway i don´t know how to restrict the animation only to messages sent by the topScroll!

how can i distinguish different senders inside of scrollViewWillBeginDragging?

probably an objective-c absolute beginners question. i hope someone will give me a hint anyway.

thank you!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // rootScroll
    [rootScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [rootScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 1980)];

    // topScroll    
    [topScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [topScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(3072, 406)];

    // bottomScroll
    [bottomScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [bottomScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(3072, 188)];
}


- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"will begin dragging, %i", sender);

    [UIScrollView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:0.15f];
    [self.bottomScroll setAlpha:0.0];
    [UIScrollView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"end position");

    [UIScrollView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIScrollView setAnimationDuration:1.5f];
    [self.bottomScroll setAlpha:1.0];
    [UIScrollView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `tag` propeties of the scrollviews in Interface Builder.  You can then use `[sender tag]` in your method to tell them apart.

Comment: aaaah. thanks a ton! i´ve seen examples where people retrieved the [sender tag] parameter. but haven´t seen where i can set it.

Comment: @user627070, `tag` is a property of `UIView`, so you can set it programatically or via IB if you prefer.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView

Comment: i was looking only to the properties of UIScrollView. but as it inherits from UIView i should do better next time. thanks again!

Comment: if (sender==topScroll) {...} would also do fine.